# why does imagettftext() takes a different string value as input when input string is obtained from rand() function?

Tags: php, reference

I am trying to create a captcha image and store the value in session variable.

**Captcha.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

function rand_str() {
    $range = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $i0=rand(0,35);
    $i1=rand(0,35);
    $i2=rand(0,35);
    $i3=rand(0,35);
    return $range[$i0].$range[$i1].$range[$i2].$range[$i3];
}
$str_captcha = rand_str();
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $str_captcha;

$im       = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 70);
$color    = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 30, 30, $color, 'fonts/Ewert-Regular.ttf', $str_captcha);

header('Content-type: image/png');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, proxy-revalidate');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

**Check.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['captcha'].'<br>';
?>
```

### My Test Cases

---

**Scenario 1 :**
For Example, if Check.php gives DMJF (generated actual value), then Captcha.php gives different image, for instance, 77B0.

If i use

```
$str_captcha = "ABCD";
```

instead of

```
$str_captcha = rand_str();
```

it works fine. Captcha.php gives ABCD image and Check.php gives ABCD string.

**Scenario 2 :**
If i use the following

```
$i0=11;
$i1=12;
$i2=13;
$i3=14;
```

instead of

```
$i0=rand(0,35);
$i1=rand(0,35);
$i2=rand(0,35);
$i3=rand(0,35);
```

it also works fine. Captcha.php gives BCDF image and Check.php gives BCDF string.

**Scenario 3 :**
If i use the following

```
$i0=11;
$i1=12;
$i2=rand(0,35);
$i3=rand(0,35);
```

it also works fine for last two characters. but the first two characters are different.
For Example, if Check.php gives **BC**JF (generated actual value), then Captcha.php gives partially correct image, for instance, **BC**0M.

Please help me that why does the function imagettftext() takes a different value if I use rand() function.

Comment: What do you mean by different? Different from what? When you use `rand()`, you get different random numbers every time, that's the point.

Comment: As i have mentioned in example, if `$str_captcha` is assigned a value using `rand()` and has value 'GH8U', then image produced if different. say for instance, an image of 'A7D0'.

In short, `echo $str_captcha` would gives GH8U
But the image produced is A7D0